# Winston logger console log by third party modules

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using third-party modules which does console.log and there is no way to configure a custom logger for those modules. Is there any way I can reconfigure my app to pass all console.log and console.error to Winston logger?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387738/how-to-make-winston-logging-library-work-like-console-log

Comment: I used 
console.info = (message, params) => {
 this.logger.info(`Using Console:${message}`, params);
};
console.warn = (message, params) => {
 this.logger.warn(`Using Console:${message}`, params);
};

The problem console.log("hello","Bob"); prints hello {"0":"B","1":"o","2":"b"}

Answer (score 2):

I also recently wanted such a solution where my app is using winston for logging but there are some third party libs that use console logs directly.
I wanted to redirect those messages through winston too.
Here is a simplified snippet

```
const main_logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format.json()
     ),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({format: winston.format.cli()}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: `${LOG_DIR}/app.error.log`, level: 'error'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: `${LOG_DIR}/app.log`})
    ]
})

const consoleLogger = function(level, message, ...params) {
    main_logger.log(level, message)
    if(params.length > 0) {
        main_logger.log(level, JSON.stringify(params))
    }
}

console.log =  (...args) => {consoleLogger('info', ...args)}
console.info = (...args) => {consoleLogger('info', ...args)}
console.error = (...args) => {consoleLogger('error', ...args)}
console.warn = (...args) => {consoleLogger('warn', ...args)}
```

I do this in a `logger.js` file that gets included into all other files that need a logger.